# Submit html form when hitting enter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the login form to be submitted whether we click on the login button or by hitting Enter Key.

The HTML form is:

```
 <form id="myForm" role="form" class="login-form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" id="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="form-password" id="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
 </div>
    <button type="button" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
</form>
```

I used the following method in jQuery:

```
var loginFunction = function(){
var userTxt = document.getElementById("form-username").value;
var passTxt = document.getElementById("form-password").value;
if(userTxt !="" && passTxt != "")
{
    $.ajax({
        url: './php/login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {user: userTxt, pass: passTxt},

        success:function(res3)
        {
            if(res3=="correct")
            {
                window.location.href='./pages/home.php';
            }
        },
        error:function(res3) {
            if(res3=="incorrect")
            {
                alert("Username and Password are incorrect");
            }
        }
    })

}
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#loginBtn").on('click', loginFunction);
    $("#form-password").keypress(function(event)
    {
        if(event.which == 13)
        {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $("loginBtn").click();
        }

    });
});
```

The on click method is working properly but when I hit enter in any place in the form nothing happened, plus if the username and password are incorrect I can't see the alert message.

Comment: `$("#loginBtn").click();` missing `#`

Comment: '$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});' for key bindings !

Comment: You can also trigger the click event with `trigger()`

`$("#loginBtn").trigger("click");`

Comment: All your solutions worked fine. Now when Json respond "Incorrect" I can't see the alert message, but when it respond "correct" it redirect to the after login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    alert('submit form');
    //Submit form
    $('form#myForm').submit();
    // your validations and ajax call goes here..
    return false;    //<---- Add this line
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" role="form" class="login-form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" id="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="form-password" id="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
 </div>
    <button type="button" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the button type to `submit`. On doing this the form will respond to `enter/return` event and will trigger first available submit button.

To submit the form on click of 'submit' button 
`$("#myForm").submit(function(event)` will be enough.

Using `event.preventDefault()` since the form is submitted using ajax.Without, the form will get submitted but ajax wont fire

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    loginFunction();
  })
})


var loginFunction = function() {
  alert('Hello');
  //rest of the code


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" role="form" class="login-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" id="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="form-password" id="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("#loginBtn").on('click', loginFunction);

    $("#form-password").keypress(function(event)
    {
        if(event.which == 13)
        {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $("loginBtn").click();
        }

    });

    $("#loginBtn").bind('keydown', function(e){         
        if (e.which == 13){
           $('#loginBtn').trigger('click');   
        }     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**loginBtn** selector is wrongly given.
Please use **#** for the id selector.

```
if(event.which == 13)
    {           
        $("#loginBtn").click();
    }
```

and write call the function **loginFunction** on the event of loginBtn click.

```
$( "#loginBtn" ).click(function() {

  loginFunction();

});
```